# Multiple Block Parameters with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, parameters

I'm trying to get this Sinatra GET request to work:

```
get '/:year/:month/:day/:slug' do

end
```

I know you can get one param to work with block parameters:

```
get '/:param' do |param|
  "Here it is: #{param}."
end
```

But how can I use multiple block parameters with the first code block? I'm open to other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple placeholders are stored in `params` as Hash.

```
# Request to /2009/10/20/post.html

get '/:year/:month/:day/:slug' do
  params[:year]  # => 2009
  params[:month] # => 10
  params[:day]   # => 20
  params[:post]  # => post.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my ignorance of Sinatra, but shouldn't this set named parameters like Rails `map.connect`?:

```
get '/:year/:month/:day/:slug
```

Now the parameters should be accessible in the `params` hash:

```
params = { :year => "foo", :month => "bar", :day => "baz", :slug => "etc" }
```